# Windows software to browse SVN repository that isn't TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, client

Because of an unfortunate Windows limitation (no more than 16 icon overlays in Windows Explorer) TortoiseSVN is not a viable client for me on computers with the TFS shell extension installed. I've spent some time browsing [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients), but there is a lot of crap on that list. QSvn was close but doesn't let you browse before doing a checkout. SmartSVN is pretty good but expensive ($79 single user). Anyone know of a standalone (not ide/shell integrated) GUI SVN client for Windows?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but would Tortoise work if you turned off the overlays? I don't have Tortoise handy to check that out, but it might be an option.

Comment: Yes, you can switch off (even configure) Tortoise's overlays. It might be less useful without them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the TortoiseSVN [icon overlays in the settings](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay) (Status Cache = None). You can use the "check modifications" or commit dialog instead to examine the status of your working copy.

In my experience (on windows XP) the icon overlays are not desirable anyway because they are either unreliable (because updated with low priority) or they slow down explorer.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, with TortoiseSVN, browsing a repository does not use the overlays, they are only used for your working copy to indicate status.

Is the problem really with browsing?

Comment: It should also be possible to turn the Icon overlays off in Tortoise Subversion - disable them for all drive types in the settings. Mind you, I did just try this myself, and the overlays were still displayed - maybe a reboot-needed issue or something.

Comment: Can I turn off the part where it decides it needs to be loaded into every IE process?

Comment: @jeff: do you mean the icon overlays or the right-click context menu? I believe the answer is yes to both.

Answer (score 1):

I like [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) for browsing and managing repositories.  It has the advantage of also being cross platform.

It meets your requirements of not being ide/shell integrated.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Ankhsvn (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) if you are using Visual Studio. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need browsing, I'd recommend just going with a Web based tool for ease of maintenance.  If you host your repository on Apache already, the default Web access that you get by just browsing to your repository URL is OK; for added features, [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

[WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) is the best way to just browse.  Works on every platform and from any location.  I highly recommend using that instead of some local client.